# Customizing Wordpress Admin menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to customize the wordpress dashboard left-side menu. I want to remove the sub-menus by hovering, instead I want to show them in the menu without hovering. For example when we hover mouse on the 'Pages', the submenu with 'All pages' and 'Add new' appears. I would like to show these options in menu without hovering it. 
I'll appreciate any help or any hint to  get started with.

[image]

Comment: I think this post should be at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already get this functionality by clicking on "Pages", instead of hovering

[image: Word Press Admin Menu]

If you want the menu options pre-expanded, this plugin will work as well: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/expanded-admin-menus/

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-admin-bar/